# Stacking ON clauses with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, relational-database

I saw this join and I was wondering where this syntax comes from.

```
SELECT *
  FROM [dbo].[AA] 
INNER JOIN dbo.BB 
INNER JOIN dbo.CC ON BB.ID = CC.BB_ID
                  ON AA.ID = BB.AA_ID
```

It is strange that I can only refer to tables `BB` and `CC` on the first `ON` clause and not to table `AA`.

Normally I write down first table name and then the join condition.

```
SELECT *
  FROM [dbo].[AA]
INNER JOIN dbo.BB ON AA.ID = BB.AA_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.CC ON BB.ID = CC.BB_ID
```

My questions are what is the background of the first syntax and if there is any influence on the execution, so far I did not see it.

Comment: It's a poor way of writing a join--just like someone not using the ON clause and instead putting everything in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

I believe all that is happening here is that the query is joining your `CC` table to your `BB` table rather than `AA`, as if it was a sub-query.  If you change the layout of your query a little you will be able to see this nested joining in the same way you would a `case` expression:

```
select *
from [dbo].[AA]
    inner join dbo.BB
                inner join dbo.CC
                on BB.ID = CC.BB_ID
    on AA.ID = BB.AA_ID;
```

Comment: So it limits the scope of the join, any thoughts on execution?